# SQL UPDATE + SELECT SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas

clima_laboral_estructura En esta almaceno las respuestas a 10 interrogantes y sumatoria producto del resultado de una encuesta en el ultimo registro Total_Respuesta

[image: tabla 1]

clima_laboral_departamento En esta almaceno, los departamentos y el total de respuestas - las cuales procederán de la sumatoria de por ejemplo la tabla anterior.

[image: tabla 2]

Mediante un

```
SELECT SUM(Total_Respuesta) AS Total_Respuesta 
FROM clima_laboral_estructura
```

Obtengo el resultado total de la 1ra tabla clima_laboral_estructura

Mas quiero con un Update ingresar dicho resultado a la 2da tabla clima_laboral_departamento

He estado probando varias opciones, sin embargo sin éxito alguno.

dejo la ultima consulta que funciono, mas no me agrega los datos a la 2da tabla

```
UPDATE clima_laboral_departamento SET Total =( SELECT Total_Respuesta 
FROM clima_laboral_estructura WHERE ( SELECT SUM(Total_Respuesta) AS 
Total_Respuesta FROM clima_laboral_estructura ) )
```

Esperando su ayuda, colaboración o sugerencias.

Answer (score 3):

Hola suponiendo que el campo que relaciona las dos tablas es "id_du", quedaría algo como esto:

```
UPDATE clima_laboral_departamento cld
SET total_departamento = 
    (
    SELECT SUM(cle.total_respuesta) 
    FROM clima_laboral_estructura cle 
    WHERE cle.id_du = cld.id_du
    )
WHERE cld.id_du = 1; --id del departamento
```

El WHERE del subquery que suma el total de respuesta, debe relacionar el "id_du" de la tabla: "clima_laboral_departamento" y "clima_laboral_estructura".

```
WHERE cle.id_du = cld.id_du
```

Comment: Gracias por la informacion, apenas acabo de verla, pero no, lamentablemente creo no haberme explicado bien. Ya que lo que quiero insertar es SELECT SUM(Total_Respuesta) AS Total_Respuesta, la suma de todos los registros de la 1ra tabla, en la 2da tabla. hacer la consulta y el resultado agregarlo a la 2da tabla.